# How to diagnose a 401 error attempting to get an OAuth2 bearer token in c# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, paypal, oauth-2.0

I have some limited skills in `c++` and have recently moved in `C# (asp.net)` and `azure Web services`. As a PoC I'm trying to make `REST` calls into `PayPal` (which I'll need to be using professionally in 3 -6 months).

I've set up my personal `PayPal` account using the instructions [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) and I get a bearer token back using curl as described in the link. Awesome.

I'm now trying to do this from `.NET Core C#` and all I get is a `401 error`. I've examined the request and it seems the same as the curl in terms of headers; the `base64` encoded credentials I think I'm adding are the same as the ones in the verbose curl log (I examined the two `base64` strings by eye) so it must be something I'm doing (or not doing) in the set up of the call. I'm looking for suggestions, pointers, or flat out laughter at the obvious mistake I've made.

I've set up what I believe to be a named client thus:

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient("PayPal", c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/");
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en_US");
            });
```

(with all the other stuff that comes free with VS under it omitted for brevity).

I attempt the call thus:

```
           string clientCredString = CLIENTID + ":" + SECRET;
            var clientCreds = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientCredString);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("PayPal");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", System.Convert.ToBase64String(clientCreds));
            var messageBody = new Dictionary<string,string > ();
            messageBody.Add("grant_type", "client_credientials");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "oauth2/token")
            {
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(messageBody)
            };
            string token;
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);

            }
            else 
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Well that failed");
            }
```

and get a `401` code for my trouble.

Suggestions for troubleshooting, better methods of doing this and laughter at my foolishness all welcomed.

Comment: Not sure it's causing your issue, but typo in `"client_credientials"`

Comment: @PrestonPHX it's not going to help is it? Good catch and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I read the documentation, a couple of items stand out to me:

- Requires a verb of post.
- Uses `FormUrlEncodedContent` for client credentials.
- Basic auth requires username and password (Client Id & Secret)

I believe the syntax should be:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "...");
request.Content = new Dictionary<string, string>() { "grant_type", "client_credentials" };
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{id}:{secret}")}");
HttpResponseMEssage = response = await client.PostAsync(request);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: This code also gives a 401. Where's a good place to start diagnosing wider issues? I've looked in the headers being sent back and there doesn't seem to be anything helpful.

Comment: yes I have and it works fine (and apologies for the delay in responding).

Comment: You sure that you are encoding to the correct format?

Comment: no I'm not. I'm using the code I posted and the snippet you suggested. How would you encode the request and what's the best way to verify it's being done right?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers:

It was, as suggested, an encoding problem. The line:

```
var clientCreds = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientCredString);
```

needed to be

```
var clientCreds = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientCredString);
```

It should also be noted that this particular operation requires a POST not a GET as I was using, but once I started sending properly encoded requests the errors started to make a lot more sense.